# C++ mixing unqiue_ptr with raw pointer for the same object

Tags: c++

I've been working through some exercises with algorithms in an effort to learn c++. I was coding a word trie and thought about a solution that mixed unique_ptr with a raw pointer for the same object. I watched a lecture where the speaker was discussing to not over use unique_ptr and shared_ptr. They also mentioned raw pointers are good as long as there is no ownership implied. I'm sure this can be implemented in another way but I wanted to understand if there are issues that I'm not seeing. For all I know this is a common practice or the dumbest thing you can do. Here is a bit of the class.

```
class node {
public:
    node(node * parent) :
        parent { parent } {
    }

    void insert(const std::string & word, int index) {
        auto c = word[0];
        if (children[c-'a'] == nullptr) {
            children[c-'a'] = std::make_unique(this);
        }

        if(!word.size()>1) {
            children[c-'a']->tnsert(word.substr(1), index);
        }
        else {
            occurrences.push_back(index);
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> & find(const std::string & word) const {
        auto c = word[0];
        if (children[c-'a'] != nullptr) {
            if(!word.size()>1) {
                return children[c-'a']->find(word.substr(1);
            }
            else {
                return children[c-'a'];
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    node * parent;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> children(26);
};
```

I choose to hold the nodes in the vector as unique_ptrs for two reasons memory and an empty slot has significant meaning in the algorithm. In the insert method when creating a child I used the this in it's constructor. I was even thinking that the find method could have been implemented with raw pointers as:

```
 node * find(const std::string & word) const;
```

I would just need to add a member like node * get_raw() { return this; } and instead of returning the child as unique_ptr just return get_raw();. I know there are lots of ways to code this differently. I could have used std::unique_ptr & parent. The raw pointer is just easier for the root node which has no parent.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think I missed it... What was the question?

Comment: `node * get_raw() { return this; } `.  `unique_ptr` has a `get` method.

Comment: And yeah, `std::unique_ptr<node> &` doesn't make much sense unless the caller wants to be able to modify the `unique_ptr` itself.

Comment: `find` should not return `std::unique_ptr<node> &`, but `const node*`. As you wrote yourself, "raw pointers are good as long as there is no ownership implied".

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't have a container holding smart pointers. The whole point of using a STD container like `std::vector` is to have it manage memory of raw pointers for you. In fact, there's no gain in having a vector of `unique_ptr`s. Reasons in favour are very few and narrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vector` of `unique_ptrs` is legit, a benefit is that you can call `children.clear(),` and every pointer will be properly deleted.

You should only return a `unique_ptr& or unique_ptr*` if you want to modify the `unique_ptr` object.

Returning a `unique_ptr` doesn't give you any benefit over returning a raw pointer using `get()`, because at the end of the day you need to `test` for `nullptr` in both cases.

Also, your find function is not properly written:

```
std::unique_ptr<node> & find(const std::string & word) const {
    auto c = word[0];
    if (children[c-'a'] != nullptr) {
        if(!word.size()>1) {
            return children[c-'a']->find(word.substr(1);
        }
        else {
            return children[c-'a'];
        }
    }

    // nullptr will be converted to a local unique_ptr object. you cannot
    // return a reference to a local object that's about to be destroyed.
    // return nullptr;

    static const std::unique_ptr<node> empty;
    return empty;
}

// Or
node* find(const std::string & word) const 
{
    return children[c-'a'].get();
}
```